# monolog.logger.db service has been removed

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to refactor some Symfony 3 code to Symfony 4.

I am getting the following error when attempting to log:

> The "monolog.logger.db" service or alias has been removed or inlined
>   when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or
>   stop using the conta     iner directly and use dependency injection
>   instead.

My logging code:

```
$logger = $container->get('monolog.logger.db');
        $logger->info('Import command triggered');
```

Monolog config:

```
monolog:
    channels: ['db']
    handlers:
        db:
            channels: ['db']
            type: service
            id: app.monolog.db_handler
```

app.monolog.db_handler config (Note, I tried `public: true` here and it had no affect:

```
app.monolog.db_handler:
    class: App\Util\MonologDBHandler
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

How can I get this wired up correctly in Symfony 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `App\Util\MonologDBHandler` may be the only thing that is actively using `monolog.logger.db` - via a `container->get('...')` call. (If not, you will want to use this technique to tag the specific sort of logger into more services).

You would be better to allow the framework to build the `app.monolog.db_handler` service itself, and use the container to help to build it. Normally, to inject a logger service, you will just need to type-hint it:

```
// in App\Util\MonologDBHandler.php
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null) {...}
```

However, that will, by default, setup with the default `@logger`, so you need to add an extra hint in the service definition of the handler that you want a [different type of logger](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#monolog-logger):

```
services:
    App\Log\CustomLogger:
        arguments: ['@logger']
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger, channel: db }
```

Now, the logger in `CustomLogger` should be what you had previously known as `monolog.logger.db`.

You can also alias a different interface (similar to how the LoggerInterface is aliased to inject '@logger') to the allow for the tagging.

Answer (score 4):

By default all [services in Symfony 4 are `private`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services) (*and is the recommended pratice*) so you need to "inject" in each Controller each needed service (*personally I use a custom CommonControllerServiceClass*).

You can also create a public [service "alias"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html) to continue accessing the service as you did, but it's not the best pratice to follow (*also because I guess you will have many other services to fix*).

```
mylogger.db:
    alias: monolog.logger.db
    public: true
```

then you can get the service from the container:

```
$logger = $container->get('mylogger.db');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alister's answer is a good start, but you can utilise service arguments binding instead of creating a new service for each logger:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        bind:
            $databaseLogger: '@monolog.logger.db'
```

Then just change the argument name in your class:

```
// in App\Util\MonologDBHandler.php 

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

public function __construct(LoggerInterface $databaseLogger = null) {...}
```